# Appengine: GCS How to make a single cloudstorage file public-read in python

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

I am using the googlecloudstorageclient for manipulating files in a bucket. The bucket is not and should not be public readable, but I need to set public-read ({'x-goog-acl': 'public-read'}) for single files via python code.

**How can I programmatically in python change the ACL or metadata on an existing GCS-file to public-read or remove that?**

I tried copy2(), but it resets the content-type to binary/octet-stream if I pass in permissions.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions

Answer (score 0):

Use the [listbucket](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#listbucket) method to iterate through the bucket and get the content-type from [GCSFileStat](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/gcsfilestat_class) for each file.

Now use the copy2 method and provide the metadata dict with the values from GCSFileStat and modify the ACL in that dict.

Comment: I will try: copy2(src, dst, {'x-goog-acl': 'public-read', 'content-type': 'application/json'}) and report how it worked later. This seems to be a comprehensive list of options:  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-headers

Comment: @cat that will work only if all the files are json format. If some files are text files, some are images there is no other option but to use listbucket

Comment: Thanks this does work for now as expected (application/json is an example). The JSON/dict parameter seems to accept arbitrary stuff. I would directly use cloudstorage.stat() to get the GCSFileStat instead of listbucket, as I already have the source path. Using cloudstorage in appengine spreads beta-software feeling.

Comment: yeah. if you know the file path of all the files, then you could use stat() method, else you can use listbucket. Accept the answer if it is fine or post your own answer. Cheers

Comment: The listbucket() function __does not return the content_type__ (gcs_file_stat.content_type is None!), so this is not an option. As I said, GCSlib is a hack, but probably they just save some costly RPC calls. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#listbucket

Answer (score 0):

You can use [objects patch](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/patch) to change the acl or metadata of an object. [This code example](https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-acl-insert-delete/blob/master/api_test.py) (using insert acl) shows you how to use the [cloud storage apiclient](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/python/latest/storage_v1.bucketAccessControls.html#patch) and send an authorized api request using appengine.